# Concept of a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Question: Give an example of a normal subgroup of $A_4$. Is the subgroup 
$H$={$(1),(25)(34),(35)(24),(45)(23)$} of $A_5$ a normal subgroup?
I am having a hard time understanding this concept because the question itself is confusing me. Do I have to come up with a group showing $A_4$? Is $A_4$=[$(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(123)$}? Need help

Comment: $A_5$ is a simple group, so it has no proper non-trivial normal subgroups. You're looking for subgroups of $A_4$ anyway!

Comment: How do I go about finding that out? For example: Can $A_4$={$(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(123)$}?

Comment: Take the Klein four group 
$K = \{ (1), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$.

Comment: After that, I can just say $H$ is not in normal in $A_4$?

Comment: @LadyT Are you familiar with the concept of a normal subgroup? A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called *normal* if for any $g \in G$, the left and right cosets of $H$ coincide, that is

$$gH = Hg.$$

We then write $H \trianglelefteq G$.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg know the definition but incorporating into a problem is give me trouble

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg I see now, I have to take the conjugation of an element in $H$ to see if $H$ is $A_5$